# MYSQL Workbench export will not source correctly in mysql (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having a problem using the source command in mysql to import a create script from mysql workbench.

The export works fine if I paste it into the sql box on PhpMYAdmin but when I use source in mysql on ubuntu it looks like it is working but none of the tables are there.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `techforceapp` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `techforceapp` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`techs`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`techs` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`techs` (
  `idtechs` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `zip` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `sms` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `twitter` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `facebook` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `linkedin` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `dateadded` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT now() ,
  `enddate` DATETIME NULL ,
  `paylevel1` FLOAT NULL ,
  `paylevel2` FLOAT NULL ,
  `paylevel3` FLOAT NULL ,
  `admin` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtechs`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`customers` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`customers` (
  `idcustomers` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `zip` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `referral` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `discount` INT NULL ,
  `sms` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `twitter` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `facebook` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `linkedin` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `dateadded` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT now() ,
  `role` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `notes` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcustomers`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`status`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`status` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`status` (
  `idstatus` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idstatus`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`jobs`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`jobs` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`jobs` (
  `idjobs` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `customers_idcustomers` INT NOT NULL ,
  `invoiceprice` FLOAT NULL ,
  `discount` INT NULL ,
  `milage` INT NULL ,
  `locations_idlocations` INT NULL ,
  `redo` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `redojobid` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `date` DATETIME NULL ,
  `dateadded` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT now() ,
  `assignedtechid` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `description` TEXT NULL ,
  `nextaction` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `nextactiondate` DATETIME NULL ,
  `status_idstatus` INT NOT NULL ,
  `taxes` FLOAT NULL ,
  `quotedamount` FLOAT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idjobs`) ,
  INDEX `fk_jobs_customers` (`customers_idcustomers` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_jobs_status1` (`status_idstatus` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_jobs_customers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customers_idcustomers` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`customers` (`idcustomers` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_jobs_status1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status_idstatus` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`devices`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`devices` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`devices` (
  `iddevices` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `os` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `serial` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `notes` TEXT NULL ,
  `customers_idcustomers` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iddevices`) ,
  INDEX `fk_devices_customers1` (`customers_idcustomers` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_devices_customers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customers_idcustomers` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`customers` (`idcustomers` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`accessories`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`accessories` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`accessories` (
  `idaccessories` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `description` VARCHAR(140) NULL ,
  `quantity` INT NULL ,
  `jobs_idjobs` INT NOT NULL ,
  `devices_iddevices` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idaccessories`) ,
  INDEX `fk_accessories_jobs1` (`jobs_idjobs` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_accessories_jobs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jobs_idjobs` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`jobs` (`idjobs` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`lineitems`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`lineitems` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`lineitems` (
  `idlineitems` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `jobs_idjobs` INT NOT NULL ,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `price` FLOAT NULL ,
  `tax` FLOAT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(140) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlineitems`) ,
  INDEX `fk_lineitems_jobs1` (`jobs_idjobs` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lineitems_jobs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jobs_idjobs` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`jobs` (`idjobs` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`joblogs`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`joblogs` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`joblogs` (
  `idjoblogs` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `text` TEXT NULL ,
  `jobs_idjobs` INT NOT NULL ,
  `techs_idtechs` INT NOT NULL ,
  `entrydate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT now() ,
  `techtime` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idjoblogs`) ,
  INDEX `fk_joblogs_jobs1` (`jobs_idjobs` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_joblogs_techs1` (`techs_idtechs` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_joblogs_jobs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jobs_idjobs` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`jobs` (`idjobs` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_joblogs_techs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`techs_idtechs` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`techs` (`idtechs` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`locations`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`locations` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`locations` (
  `idlocations` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `customers_idcustomers` INT NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `zip` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `notes` TEXT NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlocations`) ,
  INDEX `fk_locations_customers1` (`customers_idcustomers` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_locations_customers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customers_idcustomers` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`customers` (`idcustomers` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`bookmarks`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`bookmarks` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`bookmarks` (
  `idbookmarks` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `description` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idbookmarks`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`company`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`company` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`company` (
  `idcompany` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `zip` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `website` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcompany`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `techforceapp`.`payments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `techforceapp`.`payments` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `techforceapp`.`payments` (
  `idpayments` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `amount` FLOAT NULL ,
  `jobs_idjobs` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpayments`) ,
  INDEX `fk_payments_jobs1` (`jobs_idjobs` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_payments_jobs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jobs_idjobs` )
    REFERENCES `techforceapp`.`jobs` (`idjobs` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `techforceapp`.`techs`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `techforceapp`;
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`techs` (`idtechs`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `phone`, `email`, `sms`, `password`, `twitter`, `facebook`, `linkedin`, `dateadded`, `enddate`, `paylevel1`, `paylevel2`, `paylevel3`, `admin`) VALUES (0, 'Admin', 'Admin', '', '', '', '', '', 'admin', NULL, '$1$TdrF#$WPr2kmoMgPunETRV0KMtA0', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);

COMMIT;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `techforceapp`.`status`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `techforceapp`;
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (1, 'New');
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (2, 'In Progress');
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (8, 'Waiting For Customer Info');
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (4, 'Waiting For Parts');
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (5, 'Waiting For Spot On Bench');
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (6, 'Waiting For Payment');
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (7, 'Waiting For Pickup');
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`status` (`idstatus`, `status`) VALUES (3, 'Completed');

COMMIT;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `techforceapp`.`company`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `techforceapp`;
INSERT INTO `techforceapp`.`company` (`idcompany`, `name`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `phone`, `email`, `website`) VALUES (0, 'PC Repair Place', '1 Yemen St', 'Yemen', 'MI', '48195', '555-555-1234', 'us@pc.com', 'www.wefixcomputers.com');

COMMIT;
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your screen capture looks like there were five statements executed (prior to the SHOW TABLES statement). That's a lot fewer lines than we would expect if you were running the script you show above.

Check the contents of that init.sql script.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'techforceapp' ;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'customers';
```

What is sql_mode set to? What is the current database?

```
SELECT @@sql_mode ;
SELECT DATABASE() ;
```